# all prefab is destroyed when the original prefab is deleted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

for example, if an original prefab is destroyed , the others are destroyed too.    there are no more cloned prefabs...
  i have to destroy the original prefab... because it is enemy...
  is there any way to make cloned prdfab forever even if the original is deleted?

```
IEnumerator timedelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("sdfaDF");
        br = Instantiate(a ,new Vector3 (-4,-6,0), Quaternion.identity ) as          GameObject;
        br.tag = "a";
        makebox();
    }


void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "a")
        {

            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            gm.mylife -= 1;

        }
    }
```

if the original prefab meets OnTriggerEnter2D , it destroyed...and then cloned prefab stop to be created. i need to make cloned prefab not to be destroyed even though the original one is destroyed.

Comment: Your code is very sloppy and incomplete, but based on what I see, you want to clone the GO "a". When it gets destroyed, of course you cannot Instantiate from it anymore... It's like. Copying a text from a sheet of paper, then you burn the "source sheet" yet still want to copy the text from it. You can't. It's not there anymore...

Comment: @Mark thank you for your critical opinion ...i figured out by using resource.load . then it works very well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to debug with the code you provided but I can think of 1 scenario. Make sure you are not in it.

You may have destroyed the original prefab, not the clone, I mean the actual prefab in **Project tab in the Editor**.

```
[SerializeField] GameObject originalPrefab; // You dragged & dropped your prefab here
var clone1 = Instantiate(originalPrefab);
var clone2 = Instantiate(originalPrefab);
var clone3 = Instantiate(originalPrefab);
var clone4 = Instantiate(originalPrefab);
Destroy(originalPrefab); // If you do this you destroy everything.
```

Instead, try this:

```
[SerializeField] GameObject originalPrefab;
var baseClone = Instantiate(originalPrefab);
var clone1 = Instantiate(baseClone);
var clone2 = Instantiate(baseClone);
var clone3 = Instantiate(baseClone);
Destroy(baseClone); // Only destroy baseClone
```

If you want to destroy all the clones you can save them in an array then loop through the array calling `Destroy()` on each.

Comment: thank you for your help.but i already figured out by using resource.load. it works very well now. i consider your opinion too.